# ASP.NET caching with web services calls

Tags: asp.net, caching

> Assume that you are developing a web application that shows currency
>   exchange rates for a bank web site. The rates are stored in an IBM
>   Mainframe in the bank and rates are available through web services.
>   Each time a user accesses the rates page, the page makes a request to
>   the mainframe. This generates too much load on the mainframe.
>   Especially most of the time the rates delivered is the same. How would
>   you design a caching architecture that minimises the trip to the web
>   service. But at the same time rates may fluctuate within the day and
>   if rates have changed the rates web page should not display the cached
>   values but make another request to the web service. How would you
>   design such a caching architecture and make sure it is invalidated on
>   rate changes? Please explain by drawing a diagram.

Can you tell me in this scenario how ASP.net will know that values are changed? what should I do?

Comment: Can you answer to this question please instead of only posting comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Mainframe" must advertise to Web that the value has changed.

So you can, for example, implement another web service called "InvalidateCache()" that would empty the cache when called.

When the rates change, "Mainframe" would call InvalidateCache service which would empty the cache so that subsequent request to the Rate service would call Mainframe for new rates.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Following is the description:

1. Make a new webservice which stores just a token, that token could be anything like datetime or you can generate the token from any other algo.
2. When the user comes to that page on which currency rates needs to be shown, browser make a hit to that new service along with token.
3. If the client token matches with the server then the service returns true response otherwise false and sends the updated token too.
4. If response is true then the browser gets data from it's cache.
5. If it's false then the browser stores the updated token and calls the main webservice gets data from there and stores it in it's cache.
6. Whenever the currency rates changes, token in new webservice needs to be updated.